# How to extract every sentence that contains certain a word

Tags: java, regex, loops

Here's what I'm looking to do, I would like to extract every sentence that contains “3G” from the wiki excerpt below

"There are nine generations of iPhone models, each accompanied by one of the nine major releases of iOS. The original 1st-generation iPhone was a GSM phone and established design precedents, such as a button placement that has persisted throughout all releases and a screen size maintained for the next four iterations. The iPhone 3G added 3G cellular network capabilities and A-GPS location. The iPhone 3GS added a faster processor and a higher-resolution camera that could record video at 480p. The iPhone 4 featured a higher-resolution 960×640."

I know I need to use regular expressions and the  .split () method. But How do I loop through to get all instances of 3G?

Comment: [`\b[A-Z][a-z]*[^.]*?3G[^.]*\.`](https://regex101.com/r/eK6hW2/1) works for your example assuming sentences don't have DOT.

Comment: `Stream.of(str.split("\\.\\s*")).filter(x -> x.contains("3G")).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far and explain what isn't working.

Comment: `(?<=^|\. )([^.]*3G[^.]*\.)` works. See [regex101 for proof](https://regex101.com/r/qW9hC6/1). It defines a sentence as a sequence of characters that end with a period, doesn't contain a period, and starts at the beginning or after a period+space.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If you want to stream the split, using `Pattern.compile("\\.\\s*").splitAsStream(str)` is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` and `contains`.

```
String[] sentArray = input.split("\\.");
List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String sentence : sentArray) {
    if (sentence.contains("3G")) {
        output.add(sentence);
    }
}       
System.out.println(">>output=" + output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this:

```
import java.util.regex;
import java.util.ArrayList;

ArrayList<String> getThreeG(String text) {
    String[] parts = text.split(".");

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("3G"); // Feel free to make it more complicated
    ArrayList<String> relevant;

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        Matcher m = r.matcher(parts[i]);
        if (m.find()) {
            relevant.add(parts[i]);
        }
    }

    return relevant;
}
```

If you're looking only for sentences that have "3G" on its own, replace the regex in the example with `"\\s3G\\s"`.